# SVM model that predicted the test set very well is only predicting target=1 at a probability of .982 (for all observations) on a new dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, prediction

I have an SVM model with optimal `C` and `gamma`, which was able to predict the test set very accurately for both `target=1` and `target=0`.

However, when I try to predict on a new dataset, it is only predicting `target=1` with same probability for all observations(.982). Is there a reason for that?

I have upsampled my minority class because it was only 13% of my training data. My **RF** model, which did not do well as on the test set compared to the **SVM** model, predicts `target=0` better: about 154 observations were placed in that class.

Comment: Was the dataset on the same scale?

Comment: yes, I scaled both the datasets.

Comment: The optimum parameters are not generalized. That's why when you use the new dataset, the model can only predict only one class.

Comment: What do you mean by generalized? Do you mean that  these optimal parameters are for the training data set and therefore there is high variance (overfitting) ? What is a possible solution to this ?

Comment: do you split the data into train and test? and then the model is not good for a new dataset?

Comment: yes, only the SVM model is giving me trouble. It is not predicting for the minority class in the new dataset. It performed well on the test set during train/test split.